# What can you put in a cable to lower a voltage from 5V to 3.3V?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, usb, voltage-divider

When charging an iPod shuffle using this cable, https://www.google.com/search?q=ipod+shuffle+charger&client=ms-android-verizon&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9odvBqoHTAhVlxlQKHTpTBcIQ_AUICCgC&biw=360&bih=559# , one typically plugs the cable into a 5 Volt AC/DC converter (like a cell phone charger). Alternatively one could use the 5V output of a USB port on a computer.

However, when measuring the voltage at the end of this cable, I get 3.3V. Why is that?

Comment: Sure you're not measuring USB data lines? That's 3.3 volt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 3.3V voltage regulator circuit board built into the plug on the cable.